# Omission of relative pronouns

Tags: grammar

I have a cat who jumps high.

I have a cat jumping high.

Are they both correct? If not, could native speakers please explain it for me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***I have a cat jumping high.***

It could mean that—

*your cat is currently jumping to great heights, or it could mean that you have a cat that is capable of jumping high*

***I have a cat who jumps high.***

This sentence implies that—

*cat has the ability (to jump high)*

Comment: **I have a cat jumping high** is not idiomatic English.

Comment: @KateBunting yes

Comment: If you mean "Yes, it is", see [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+cat+jumping+high&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: @KateBunting yes, it's not idiomatic.

Comment: You should say "No, it isn't" in that case.